# Change model return array structure

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When i request my `model::all()` i get the data like this:

```
       {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_of_numbers": "mobile",
        "pcd_accepted": null,
        "first_possible_date": "2021-03-02 15:10:50",
        "email": "example@customer.nl",
        "customer_id": "Seb",
        "customer_initials": "der",
        "customer_prefix": "seb",
        "customer_last_name": "er",
        "customer_company": "seb b.v",
        "customer_street": "fds fds fdse",
        "customer_house_number": "12",
        "customer_house_number_suffix": "A",
        "customer_zip_code": "1000ff",
        "customer_city": "test",
        "status": "blocked",
        "status_message": null,
        "delayed_answer_reason": null,
        "delayed_answer_date": null,
        "created_at": "2021-03-02T13:01:15.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-03-02T13:02:15.000000Z"
       },
```

How can i get this?

```
      {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_of_numbers": "mobile",
        "pcd_accepted": null,
        "first_possible_date": "2021-03-02 15:10:50",
        "email": "example@customer.nl",
        "customer: {
                    "id": "Seb",
                    "initials": "der",
                    "prefix": "seb",
                    "last_name": "er",
                    "company": "seb b.v",
                    "street": "fds fds fdse",
                    "house_number": "12",
                    "house_number_suffix": "A",
                    "zip_code": "1000ff",
                    "city": "test"
         },
        "status": "blocked",
        "status_message": null,
        "delayed_answer_reason": null,
        "delayed_answer_date": null,
        "created_at": "2021-03-02T13:01:15.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-03-02T13:02:15.000000Z"
      },
```

Is it possible to do this in the model? I tried using `JsonResource` but this works only if i pass 1 array and not a bulk.

`JsonResource` code:

```
class JsonResponse extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'note' => $this->note,
            'planned_completion_date' => $this->planned_completion_date,
            'pcd_accepted' => $this->pcd_accpeted,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'customer' => [
                'id' => $this->customer_id,
                'initials' => $this->customer_initials,
                'prefix' => $this->customer_prefix,
                'last_name' => $this->customer_last_name,
                'company' => $this->customer_company,
                'street' => $this->customer_street,
                'house_number' => $this->customer_house_number,
                'house_number_suffix' => $this->customer_house_number_suffix,
                'zip_code' => $this->customer_zip_code,
                'city' => $this->customer_city
            ],
            'status' => $this->status,
            'status_message' => $this->status_message,
            'delayed_answer_reason' => $this->delayed_answer_reason,
            'delayed_answer_date' => $this->delayed_answer_date,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: When you insert the data into database then you have to create data what you want

Comment: The only way to achieve this in a Model is the use of mutators (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator). Although technically possible, I strongly advice not to do this. You should make a `customers` table linked to a `customer_id` in a one-to-one relationship to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an ideea would be to try resource collections https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections